# app.yaml file - Unable to assign value 'python27 api_version' to attribute 'runtime':

Tags: python, google-app-engine, static, yaml

I am trying to deploy a very simple webpage via Google app engine but am unable to deploy the app due to some error with my yaml file.

Error:

> (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file:
>   [/home/google_gcp/parkwaypoc/app.yaml]  Unable to assign value
>   'python27 api_version' to attribute 'runtime':  Value 'python27
>   api_version' for runtime does not match expression
>   '^(?:((gs://[a-z0-9-._/]+)|([a-z][a-z0-9-]{0,29})))$'

My App.yaml file:

```
 runtime:python27
 api_version:1
 threadsafe:true

 handlers:- url:/
   static_files:www/index.html
   upload:www/index.html

 - url:/(.*)
   static_files:www/\1
   upload:www/(.*)
```

I've searched others with the same issue which hint at issues with whitespaces so they were removed but I haven't been able to resolve.

The yaml file was copied directly from Google here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website#uploading_your_files_to_google_app_engine

Sorry i'm a bit new to this.

Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Your app.yaml is *NOT* a direct cut and paste from [the indicated link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website#uploading_your_files_to_google_app_engine).  The posted yaml is hosed and does not parse correctly as yaml.

Try:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, when using the exact copy and paste  I get this error instead:
 
    (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file:       [/home/google_gcp/parkwaypoc/app.yaml]
    Unable to assign value 'python27 api_version' to attribute 'runtime':
Value 'python27 api_version' for runtime does not match expression '^(?:((gs://[a-z0-9\-\._/]+)|([a-z][a-z0-9\-]{0,29})))$'
  in "/home/google_gcp/parkwaypoc/app.yaml", line 1, column 10

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: I'm working on Google cloud shell with the repo replicated on the cloud shell instance.

Comment: I ask because that message looks like it is combining the first and second line.  Windows often confuses things with its odd line endings.

Comment: No windows involved here

Comment: funnily enough ive installed the sdk on a windows device and managed to get it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is incorrect about the YAML that the OP posted? It is a YAML document consisting of one string wrapped over multiple lines. It is probably not what the OP wanted, but it **is** correct YAML.

Comment: @Anthon : *yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here, line 6, column 15*.  EG: `handlers:- url:/`

Comment: @StephenRauch That is an error in the parser you are using. The colon `:` only has special meaning if followed by a space. http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#:%20mapping%20value// is the relevant explanation in the YAML 1.2 specification.

Comment: @Anthon, actually the parser is fine.  And if the leading space in the OP's posted yaml is intended, then the posted yaml is fine.  But...  That parsing subtlety is going to be lost on just about everyone.  In addition it is **Highly** unlikely that someone is going to post a yaml configuration file that is nothing more than a 12 line string that looks a whole lot like it should have been a data structure, except that everything is indented by one space.  So, yes valid yaml.  But, No, not useful yaml, and as stated: *Hosed*.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Check your yaml file for extra spaces in front of the lines. I had that issue when I copy pasted from the Google link. I removed the extra indents and it worked.

Comment: i had the same issue and your solution helped me ... thanks